# MethodInfo Invoke With Entity Class Parameters

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke

I have a class name of "BusinessError". I am trying to invoke this class from console application 
(Using reflection). There is a error..(I clean visual studio many times or restart)

Message = "Object of type 'RestService.RequestGetOrderDetail' cannot be converted to type 'RestService.RequestGetOrderDetail'.
"
But when ı try to invoke  BusinessHasNoError  class there is no error..

How ı can MethodInfo invoke with entity class paameters(No string,int with parameters)..

```cs
public class BusinessError
{
    public ResponseGetOrderDetail Test1(RequestGetOrderDetail requestGetOrderDetail)
    {
      ResponseGetOrderDetail responseGetOrderDetail = new ResponseGetOrderDetail(
          requestGetOrderDetail);
      return responseGetOrderDetail;
    }
}
```

vs

```cs
public class BusinessNoError
{
    public ResponseGetOrderDetail Test1(string id)
    {
        ResponseGetOrderDetail responseGetOrderDetail = new ResponseGetOrderDetail(id);
        return responseGetOrderDetail;
    }
}
```

with

```cs
public string Execute(DllInfo dllInfo)
{
      object[] parameterObject = new object[1];
      parameterObject[0] = "O19082900055";
      string dllsPath = @"C:\Scheduler\DLLs\" + dllInfo.Dll;
      string nameSpace = dllInfo.NameSpace;
      string className = dllInfo.Class;
      string methodName = dllInfo.Method;
      object result = string.Empty;
      RequestGetOrderDetail requestGetOrderDetail = new RequestGetOrderDetail();
      requestGetOrderDetail.OrderID = "O19082900055";
      parameterObject[0] = new RequestGetOrderDetail() { OrderID = "O19082900055" };
      try
      {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllsPath);
        Type typeInstance = assembly.GetType(nameSpace + "." + className);

        if (typeInstance != null)
        {
          MethodInfo methodInfo = typeInstance.GetMethod(methodName);
          ParameterInfo[] parameterInfo = methodInfo.GetParameters();
          object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeInstance, null);
          if (parameterInfo.Length == 0)
          {
            result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null);
          }
          else
          {
            //I want to send requestGetOrderDetail object to  methodInfo.Invoke !!!!!
            //result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, requestGetOrderDetail);  
            **result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parameterObject);**
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw;
      }
      return result.ToString();
}
```

[File Example](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fb504401f598ea29633193d8979ffd9120191023132419/598587)

Comment: It *sounds* like you've defined `RequestGetOrderDetail` in two places - one in the code that we can see here, and one in the dll that you're loading. Would that be right? if so: that won't work - types are defined by their assembly; two identical classes in different assemblies: are unrelated types. The best way to check would be to output `typeof(RequestGetOrderDetail).AssemblyQualifiedName` and `parameterInfo[0].ParameterType.AssemblyQualifiedName`, and compare them

Comment: I've noticed you made a number of edits to the question but formatting is still poor. Please keep in mind that there is a preview right below the editor.

Comment: Both of the same RestService.RequestGetOrderDetail, CallFarmakodWebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke takes the parameters as an object[]; (and nothing else)
So your Call should be

```
Invoke(classInstance, new object[] { new RequestGetOrderDetail() {OrderId=..}; });
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.. It depends on References dll (instance object) .. when move request and response dll to another project. Problem has been solved. But ı did not understand why ?

Comment: As MarcGravel said, you probably had the same class, with the same namespace, defined twice, in different DLL's. There is no way to make them 'equal', they are incompatible by definition.
The compiler would give you a compile-time error, but with reflection you encounter the error at runtime.